# How to compile Java code using Unicode characters in identifiers

Tags: java, unicode

First, I understand this goes against all convention and advice, but I want to do it anyway.

How can I (or is it even possible) compile Java code using Unicode characters in identifiers (method names, variable names, etc.)

I want to be able to do something like the following:

```java
public class  extends  {
    public void сделайЧтонибудь() { ... }
}
```

It is a completely ridiculous example, but you get the point.

Comment: "Unicode characters" encompass more than emoji, and Java already supports a subset of Unicode characters in its identifiers. If your question is specifically how to include emoji, you should rephrase.

Comment: *I want to be able to do something like the following.*  Why?  To make it difficult to maintain maybe?

Comment: why has this question gotten downvotes? some members of stack-overflow are making it extremely difficult for people to ask plain joe questions.

Comment: @WJS For fun, a learning experiment. Not all code has to have a purpose or be maintainable.

Comment: @Tintin I think many users confuse obvious or simple questions with bad questions. My question is plenty focused, and follows all the guidelines, so 

Comment: @Volt4! exactly.  I do not see anything wrong with it (upvoted it in hope to bring back the balance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[No, you can't.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

An identifier has to start with a so-called **Java letter** that is

> [...] a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns `true`.

[Which in turn means](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart(char))

> A character [`ch`] may start a Java identifier if and only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - [`isLetter(ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(int)) returns true
> - [`getType(ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getType(int)) returns LETTER_NUMBER
> - `ch` is a currency symbol (such as '$')
> - `ch` is a connecting punctuation character (such as '_').

The (optional) subsequent characters must be a **Java letter-or-digit**, that is

> [...] a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int)` returns `true`.

[Which in turn means](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart(char))

> A character may be part of a Java identifier if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - it is a letter
> - it is a currency symbol (such as '$')
> - it is a connecting punctuation character (such as '_')
> - it is a digit
> - it is a numeric letter (such as a Roman numeral character)
> - it is a combining mark
> - it is a non-spacing mark
> - [`isIdentifierIgnorable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable(int)) returns true for the character

**None of the above is true for either  or** , but it is for `сделайЧтонибудь` which is, in fact, a valid identifier.

---

What you could do (why bother, tho) is write a pre-processor that translates those emojis into sequences of Java letters, with its output being a java program with valid identifiers which you can finally feed to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid Java, so you can't "make" it compile. Choose a valid identifier name as defined by the specification:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Identifiers may contain "Java letters" or "Java digits", which *are* unicode, but do not allow arbitrary unicode symbols:

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII dollar sign ($, or \u0024) and underscore (_, or \u005f). The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems. The underscore may be used in identifiers formed of two or more characters, but it cannot be used as a one-character identifier due to being a keyword.

> The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039).

Comment: While this is all true, it should be stressed that “Java letters” *include* ASCII letters, but are not *limited* to ASCII letters.  All Unicode letters are allowed.  The same goes for digits.